# Flushbar Compiler problems

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am new to flushbar widget.  I build a simple code sample that results on the following compiler errors following some articles and videos on the widget.  https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar

Most of the examples depend on the onPressed click event.  In my case I need to do some processing before displaying of the flushbar message.

I tried with both versions:
 flushbar: ^1.10.0
 flushbar: ^1.9.1

Could you advise what is run with the code below?

This are the compiler errors:

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Compiler message:
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.10.0/lib/flushbar_route.dart:303:8: Error: The method 'FlushbarRoute.install' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'OverlayRoute.install'.
  void install() {
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart:41:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('install').
  void install(OverlayEntry insertionPoint) {
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flushbar-1.10.0/lib/flushbar_route.dart:311:18: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
    super.install();
                 ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is my sample code.  No errors on syntax but fails the compilation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flushbar/flushbar.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePage();
  }

}
class _MyHomePage extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flushbar')),
      body: Center(
          child:
          BottomNavigationBar(
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.today),
                title: Text('Today'), // Today button.
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business ),
                title: Text('Activities'),  // Activities.
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                title: Text('Finish'), // Finish
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          )
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:           // Today selected.
//          todayButtonPressed();
          break;
        case 1:           // Activity selected.
//          activityButtonPressed();
          break;
        case 2:           // Finish selected.
          finishButtonPressed();
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  void finishButtonPressed() async {
    // Processing record.
    // .....
    // ....
    displayFlushBar(context);
  }

  void displayFlushBar(BuildContext context) {
    Flushbar(
      title: 'Action',
      message: 'Is prohibited',
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.info_outline,
        size: 28,
        color: Colors.blue.shade300,
      ),
      leftBarIndicatorColor: Colors.blue.shade300,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    )..show(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on `flushbar 1.10.0` as mentioned in this [ticket](https://github.com/AndreHaueisen/flushbar/issues/123). The issue has been fixed since Flutter 1.17. Upgrading the Flutter SDK should solve the issue, run `flutter upgrade` on your terminal to update the installed Flutter SDK.